# why have i conflict direction right to left in CSS with leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, leaflet-draw

I used the leaflet draw and now I have a problem editing, the map and editing doesn't work with Google Chrome.I realized that this is a problem with  CSS(direction right to left). How can I fix it now?

Comment: Pls share code and/or a live example

Comment: body has this CSS code [direction: rtl] so when i want to edit my drawing map with change points i can not change point in chrome. like this link "http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/examples/full.html" if you add this CSS code in  inspect element for body, you can  not edit drawing map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This because of the Tooltip. Your cursor is clicked on the tooltip and not on the layer.

**Quick Fix:**
Add following to the tooltip:

```
.leaflet-draw-tooltip{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Or you use the free [Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman) library, it is working better with the RTL but not perfect. I will create a Issue on Geoman-Github and fix it.